# Using STL Data Structures

Tags: c++, stl, g++

Please help:

g++ (GCC) 3.4.4

I have two '.hpp' files: 'UnionFind.hpp' and "Graph.hpp". The content of the files is as follows:

```
#ifndef UNIONFIND_HPP
#define UNIONFIND_HPP

#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class UnionFind
{
   public:
      UnionFind(uint32_t size);
      ~UnionFind();
      int find(uint32_t target);
      void join(uint32_t a, uint32_t b);
      void print();
   private:
      uint32_t size;
      uint32_t* index;
      vector<uint32_t>** sets;
};

#endif
```

And the other:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_HPP
#define GRAPH_HPP

#include <set>

using std::set;

class Graph
{
   public:
      Graph(uint32_t width, uint32_t length, uint32_t startN, uint32_t startP, uint32_t endN, uint32_t endP);
      ~Graph();
      int cost(uint32_t a, uint32_t b);
      void set(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t cost);
      void print();
      bool inPath(uint32_t node);
   private:
      int32_t** adjList;
      uint32_t startN;
      uint32_t startP;
      uint32_t endN;
      uint32_t endP;
      set<uint32_t>* path;
      const uint32_t width;
      const uint32_t length;
      const uint32_t size;
      const uint32_t listWidth;
};

#endif
```

For some reason I get the following errors:

```
./Graph.hpp:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `set' with no type
./Graph.hpp:23: error: expected `;' before '<' token
```

I had previously run into the problem of not including 'using std::vector' in the 'UnionFind.hpp', but adding 'using std::set' to 'Graph.hpp' does not fix the problem. Also,
I've tried 'using std::set< uint32_t >', but this gives the following errors:

```
./Graph.hpp:6: error: a template-id may not appear in a using-declaration
./Graph.hpp:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `set' with no type
./Graph.hpp:23: error: expected `;' before '<' token
```

Comment: Not related to your question: your are breaking rule of three - your have destructors - but not copy constructor/assignment operator. Inherit from std::nocopyable if you do not need/want to implement copying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
set<uint32_t>* path;
```

to

```
std::set<uint32_t>* path;
```

The compiler understands set to mean the `set()` method you've declared in your class.

It's bad style to put `using ...;` in  a header file because you force that on everyone who includes your header file. Always use explicit namespaces in header files. Save `using ...;` for source files.

Comment: I've stopped using 'using namespace std' for this reason, but you're saying that using: 'using std::vector' is still too intrusive?

Comment: In a header file yes. Personally I have no trouble with `using namespace std;` in a source file. The point is that you cannot know when you write a header file where it will end up being included.

Comment: @Daeden I would say it is too intrusive in a header. It could be acceptable in small scopes in an implementation.

Comment: Very interesting. I will certainly keep that in mind. This did fix the problem, but I am very confused as to why 'using std::vector' does not cause similar errors? Could you explain this?

Comment: Because you haven't used the identifier vector for any other purpose in your other header file. But in graph.hpp you are using set as both the name of a type and the name of a method.

Comment: using is pretty evil in my mind, better to always be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Like ahs been said, it is bad style to use `using` in headers, mostly (at least at global namespace).

Alternatively, disambiguate:

```
  ::set<uint32_t>* path;
```